# Comparing word from raw_input to wanted string

Tags: python

I am trying to create a miles to km converter including an input().

```
def miles_to_km_converter (ans):
    ans = input('please enter amount of miles you wish to convert:')
    print (('you have entered:') + str(ans) + ' miles')      
    return int(ans)*1.6 
    m == ans
a = miles_to_km_converter(m)
print ("The conversion equals:")
print (str(a) + ' km')
```

I am receiving an error: `m not defined`. I can't understand whats wrong, I defined `m` as equal to the raw input `ans`.
Thanks

Comment: Please format your code as code, so that others can read it.

Comment: You haven't defined `m` anywhere.  `==` is not assignment, it's a boolean test of equivalency.  And that statement comes after your `return` anyway, which means it isn't evaluated.  Also, the value `m` you want to pass into `miles_to_km_converter()` is represented by the `ans` argument within the function.  Consider using a different name for your argument and for the `input()` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` is only defined within your function, so outside not available.
I think you mixed up a little which code should be part of the function and which should be part of the main program.

Consider this:

```
def miles_to_km_converter (m):
    return float(m)*1.6 

ans = input('please enter amount of miles you wish to convert: ')
a = miles_to_km_converter(ans)

print ('The conversion equals: ', str(round(a, 3)) + ' km')
```

**EDIT:**

If you want the user prompt be part of the function:

```
def miles_to_km_converter():
    m = input('please enter amount of miles you wish to convert: ')
    return float(m)*1.6 

a = miles_to_km_converter()

print ('The conversion equals: ', str(round(a, 3)) + ' km')
```

Comment: What if I want the input as part of the def?

Comment: Then you don't need a parameter, because the input is part of the function - I'll edit...

Answer (score 0):

In your function -

```
def miles_to_km_converter (ans):
    ans = input('please enter amount of miles you wish to convert:')
    print (('you have entered:') + str(ans) + ' miles')      
    return int(ans)*1.6 
    m == ans # let's call this line 1
```

Before line **1** you have made a **return** call. This call stops the the execution, returns what you want to return and exits the function. After **return**, nothing gets executed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

Also, on line **1**, what we are doing is comparing **m** with **ans**. This says -

```
check if ans is equal to a
```

See [python comparison operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)

What I think you want is something like this -

```
def miles_to_km_converter():
    ans = input('please enter amount of miles you wish to convert:')
    print (('you have entered:') + str(ans) + ' miles')      
    return int(ans)*1.6 
a = miles_to_km_converter()
print ('The conversion equals: ', str(round(a, 3)) + ' km')
```

Why don't we need parameter to be passed to this function?

Our function `miles_to_km_converter` does not need a variable to be passed to it from rest of the function. The purpose of our function is

```
take input -> convert it -> return it
```

But if we had a situation where we wanted to pass a variable from the rest of the script to the function, we would need a parameter. [Read here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming))

For example -

```
def miles_to_km_converter (ans):
    print (('you have entered:') + str(ans) + ' miles')      
    return int(ans)*1.6

ans = input('please enter amount of miles you wish to convert:')
# Now our variable `ans` is not accessible to the function 
# We need to explicitly pass it like -
a = miles_to_km_converter (ans)
# And then we'll print it 
print ('The conversion equals: ', str(round(a, 3)) + ' km')
```

I hope this answers your question

Comment: I see. Can you explain please once again why there is no need in parameters when using a input as part of the function?